# Where am I going wrong in deriving the formula for the scalar that will make two vectors perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra

*This question was taken from MIT OCW and Gilbert Strang's **Introduction to Linear Algebra***

With $v=(1,1)$ and $w=(1,5)$ choose a number $c$ so that $w-cv$ is perpendicular to $v$. Then find the formula that gives this number $c$ for any nonzero $v$ and $w$.

Steps I took to get $c$:

$$(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 5 \end{matrix}-c\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix})\cdot 
\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}=0$$

$$(\begin{matrix} 1-c \\ 5-c \end{matrix})\cdot \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}=0$$

$$(1-c)+(5-c)=0$$

$$6-2c=0$$

$$c=3$$

Now for the second part:

$$(\begin{matrix} { w }_{ 1 } \\ { w }_{ 2 } \end{matrix}-c\begin{matrix} { v }_{ 1 } \\ { v }_{ 2 } \end{matrix})\cdot \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}=0$$

$$(\begin{matrix} { w }_{ 1 } \\ { w }_{ 2 } \end{matrix}-\begin{matrix} c{ v }_{ 1 } \\ c{ v }_{ 2 } \end{matrix})\cdot \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}=0$$

$${ (w }_{ 1 }-c{ v }_{ 1 })+({ w }_{ 2 }-c{ v }_{ 2 })=0$$

$${ w }_{ 1 }+{ w }_{ 2 }=c{ v }_{ 1 }+c{ v }_{ 2 }$$

$${ w }_{ 1 }+{ w }_{ 2 }=c({ v }_{ 1 }+{ v }_{ 2 })$$

$$c=\frac { ({ w }_{ 1 }+{ w }_{ 2 }) }{ ({ v }_{ 1 }+{ v }_{ 2 }) } $$

I don't understand what I did wrong, in my steps or reasoning, that had led me to an answer different from the textbooks.

Hints only, please. No actual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second part, you still used $(1\; 1)$, not $v$. That is, what you did was to find $c$ so that $w-cv\perp (1\; 1)$.

Comment: $(\begin{matrix} { w }_{ 1 } \\ { w }_{ 2 } \end{matrix}-\begin{matrix} c{ v }_{ 1 } \\ c{ v }_{ 2 } \end{matrix})\cdot \begin{matrix} { v }_{ 1 } \\ { v }_{ 2 } \end{matrix}=0\Rightarrow ({ w_{ 1 }-c{ v }_{ 1 }v }_{ 1 })+(w_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 }-c{ v }_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 })\Rightarrow { w }_{ 1 }{ v }_{ 1 }+{ w }_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 }=c({ v }_{ 1 }{ v }_{ 1 }+{ v }_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 })\Rightarrow c=\frac { ({ w }_{ 1 }{ v }_{ 1 }+{ w }_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 }) }{ ({ v }_{ 1 }{ v }_{ 1 }+{ v }_{ 2 }{ v }_{ 2 }) } $

Comment: Is this correct? and it should be equivalent to $c=\frac { v\cdot w }{ v\cdot v } $ yes?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.